# Is there any way to crate arraylists based on a counter? Java/Android

Tags: java, android

```
    addDealership("BestWheels", "Deventer", arraylist1);

    addDealership("HighDealerz", "Amsterdam", arraylist2);

    addDealership("RoyalDealers", "Den Haag", arraylist3);
```

This is what I need to end up with. When the user presses the "add" button I need to add a new dealership which will have inside an array with cars. I need to be able to add/remove cars from the arrays, so I need some way to identify each one in particular.

So far my method looks like this:

```
    private static void addDealership(String name, String city, ArrayList<Car> carArrayList) {
    dealerships.add(new Dealership(name, city, carArrayList));
    carArrayCounter++;
}
```

I basically want to modify my "addDealership" method to create separate arraylists for each dealership and then be able to add/remove elements.

> Using Arraylist is a requirement, so I can't really use a HashMap although it would be a better option.
>
> Solved using @ronginat 's suggestion.

Comment: ok, and what is your actual question?

Comment: i don't really understand for which purpose you need a counter. Your aim is to modify the arraylist inside the Dealership object, right?

Comment: Exactly @AlinaJ

Comment: @CostînDavidȘtefan yes, and that makes zero sense. if you need to create a new ArrayList, 'new ArrayList<>()' is all you need

Comment: I don't find the question clear either - please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes, I've tried that but how do I access a particular array in order to add/remove elements?

Comment: @CostînDavidȘtefan but why do you need a counter?

Comment: Why not use a Map with an Integer as key to each dealership?

Comment: Not necessarily a counter but I need some way to create separate arrays with cars for each array. Then I want to be able to add/remove elements from the car array.
@ronginat it is a requirement to use arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `getCarList` in Your `Dealership` class that returns the list's reference.
You can work with that reference to use List methods `get` and `remove`.

Implement `public boolean equals(Object obj)` in your `Car` class.
Your IDEA can help with auto generate this method.

Then you'll be able to remove a `Car` from a dealership's carList.

> carList.remove(carObject);

Comment: It seems to be the most sensible option taking into consideration the fact that I must use arraylists. I'll try it and come back with an edit. Thanks for your reply @ronginat

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [HashMap](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-hashmap-in-java/) instead of an ArrayList to access you methods. As a key you could use the name for example (could be something else, but must be unique). the advantage of a HashMap is that it is made for specific element access, unlike an ArrayList.

```
HashMap<String, DealerShip> dealerShip = new HashMap<String, DealerShip>();

private static void addDealerShip(String name, String city, ArrayList<Car> carArrayList) {
    dealerShip.put(name, new DealerShip(name, city, carArrayList);
}

private static DealerShip getDealerShip(String name) {
    return dealerShip.get(name);
}
```

Comment: I think it would be the most elegant way to do it and I totally agree with you, but unfortunately arraylists are a requirement. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: in this case I would go with ronginat 's answer

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8. To identify the relevant `Dealership`:

```
final List<Dealership> dealerships = /* initialise dealerships */

//Find a dealership by name
final Dealership foundByName = dealerships.stream()
    .filter(dealership -> dealership.name().equals("Name Of Dealership"))
    .findAny()
    .orElse(null);

//Find a dealership by name and then update its list of cars
dealerships.stream()
    .filter(dealership -> dealership.name().equals("Name Of Dealership"))
    .findAny()
    .map(Dealership::carArrayList)
    .ifPresent(cars -> {
        //Update list of cars for that dealership here. For example...
        cars.add(new Car());
    })
```